# Python Script using ExecuteStreamCommand

Tags: python, apache-nifi

After doing my best to find previous questions and examples relevant to this question, and still not finding the answers that I'm looking for I figured that I would submit a question myself.

ExecuteStreamCommand seems like the perfect processor for me due to the following reasons:

- I am able to execute any Python script and avoid Jython (in a similar fashion as ExecuteScript). Jython is not an option for me.
- I can take in FlowFiles. This is necessary as my script is made to consume the output of a previous processor. Furthermore I like the idea of keeping the data under "NiFi management".
- It writes an "execution status" which will be useful for routing.

In a nutshell, what I'm trying to do with ExecuteStreamCommand is:

- Ingest the output of a previous processor (a Scrapy spider that outputs a text file with JSON lines to be exact)
- Call a python script (e.g. `python3 my_script.py`)
- Load the FlowFile that was ingested in my python script.
- Select the content of the FlowFile.
- Operate on the content of the FlowFile within python.
- Output either an updated version of the original FlowFile or create a new one.
- Continue with my NiFi flow with the updated/new FlowFile.

For clarity's sake I currently don't understand:

- How to call the python script (from the ExecuteStreamCommand Processor)
- How to load up the FlowFile from within Python
- How to update or create a new FlowFile from within Python
- How to output the updated FlowFile from Python back to NiFi.

I have come across various examples for ExecuteScript, but unfortunately these don't exactly translate to the use of the ExecuteStreamCommand.

Thank you in advance. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: ExecuteStreamCommand sends flowfile content to the standard  input stream of new python  process and transfers standard output back into flowfile content. So your python code should read from stdin and write to stdout...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From your question you say you need to invoke the Python script without using the `InvokeScriptedProcessor` or `ExecuteScript` processors because you can't use Jython. Given that requirement, you should still be able to accomplish your goal. While it requires some familiarity with the framework, all of this information is from the [`ExecuteStreamCommand` documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html).

Your "I currently don't understand" section:

- How to call the python script (from the ExecuteStreamCommand Processor)

  - In your `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor, configure the *Command Arguments* and *Command Path* properties with the following:

    - Command Arguments: `any flags or args, delimited by ;` (i.e. `/path/to/my_script.py`)
    - Command Path: `/path/to/python3`
- How to load up the FlowFile from within Python

  - The flowfile content will be passed via *STDIN*, so in your Python script, process that data the same way you would normally process *STDIN*.
- How to update or create a new FlowFile from within Python

  - NiFi handles the flowfile creation in the framework. Any data passed by your Python script to *STDOUT* will be populated into the content of the resulting flowfile passed to the *output stream* relationship of the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor. Your script does not need to have any awareness of "flowfiles" in this instance. If you were instead using the `ISP` or `ES` processors, you could use the NiFi scripting API which is automatically injected into the scripts to create or update the flowfile object.
- How to output the updated FlowFile from Python back to NiFi.

  - Again, simply write the desired flowfile content to *STDOUT* from your script, and (given a return status code of `0`) NiFi will generate a new flowfile with that content. If you set the *Output Destination Attribute* property of `ESC` to a non-null value, NiFi will instead update the existing flowfile with a new attribute of the same name containing the output of the script.

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure to try this out. Regardless this answers all of my questions!

Comment: Yes, `ExecuteScript` can only use Jython with Python 2.7 at this time.

Comment: @Andy - Can you explain how to access session inside my python script which is executing by ExecuteStreamCommand?

Comment: Python code executed with `ExecuteStreamCommand` will not have access to the NiFi session because it is executing outside of the NiFi context.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, one more question, How to navigate exception occured in python script to non-zero status relationship ?

Comment: @ChetanHirapara you can use try-except in the script and write back the error with print statement in except block along with sys.exit(1). 

Also, you can ignore bulletin errors by marking bulletin level as None from the settings tab of the processor.